# Writing OutputStream Pipleline multiple times error - java

Tags: java, pipeline

I try to communicate with the process by using this way:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/home/username/Desktop/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f /home/username/Desktop/mosesdecoder/model/moses.ini");

while (true) {
    OutputStream stdin = null;
    InputStream stderr = null;
    InputStream stdout = null;
    stdin = process.getOutputStream();
    stderr = process.getErrorStream();
    stdout = process.getInputStream();

    // "write" the parms into stdin
    line = "i love you" + "\n";
    stdin.write(line.getBytes());
    stdin.flush();
    stdin.close();
    // Print out the output
    BufferedReader brCleanUp =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    while ((line = brCleanUp.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("[Stdout] " + line);
    }
    brCleanUp.close();
}
```

This works fine. However, I am stuck with a problem when I write the pipeline more than one time. That is - I can write to the Outputstream pipeline more than one time. The error is (for the 2th iteration):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: **Stream Closed**
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:297)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.**flush(BufferedOutputStream.java**:140)
at moses.MOSES.main(MOSES.java:60)
```

So, is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: Stop closing the output stream (or any of the streams you want to reuse) in the `while {}` loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your `while {}` loop, you are calling stdin.close().  The first time through the loop, the stream is retrieved from the Process and happens to be open.  On the first iteration of the loop, the stream is retrieved from the process, written to, flushed, and closed(!).  Subsequent iterations of the loop then get the same stream from the process, but it was closed on the first iteration of the loop (!), and your program throws an `IOException`.

Comment: Hi, If I do not close the stream, it will also be stuck in another problem (halt(!)). It seems like the close statement has to come after the flush!

Comment: I've tried another time when I  do not put close after flush, but the problem is halt after finishing the first iteration!

Comment: I'm not saying you should never close the stream, I am just saying that you should only close the stream once you are finished writing to it.  I'm not sure what problem you are running into now.

Comment: Maybe you have a little bit mis-understood for my question! I mean, I run a Machine Translation toolkit. An user enters an input sentence, and the output shows out a translating sentence. I have to write to the stdin, before to translate, and to show the stdout, hence another time, I re-write the stdin when the user enter another translating sentence. Tks!